AWS-Amplify: The tokens could not be refreshed: The token has been revoked
I have a code where, when the user tries to query a route, it checks the token in this way:
final AuthSession result = await Amplify.Auth.fetchAuthSession(
  options: const FetchAuthSessionOptions(
    forceRefresh: true,
  )
);
result as CognitoAuthSession;


In some cases, it returns this error:

SessionExpiredException {
"message": "The tokens could not be refreshed",
"recoverySuggestion": "Invoke Amplify.Auth.signIn to re-authenticate the user",
"underlyingException": "NotAuthorizedException {\\n  message=Refresh Token has been revoked,\\n}"
}

Could someone help me by explaining why this error occurs and if there's a way to work around it without the user needing to log in again?
I read the Amplify documentation but didn't find a clear explanation about this issue

Are you able to share your Amplify configuration? It looks like refreshing tokens is not enabled
